# Error when uploading a video file as a block blob on Azure using PHP SDK

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage

I was trying to upload a video of size close to 50 MB using Azure's PHP SDK.

I ran into this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method MicrosoftAzure\\Storage\\Blob\\Models\\CreateBlobOptions::getUseTransactionalMD5() in /var/www/<domain>/vendor/microsoft/azure-storage-blob/src/Blob/BlobRestProxy.php on line 1941
```

It only happens if I pass blob options to set correct mime type (video/mp4 in this case). If I upload the same video without setting blob options then it works just fine. Many other videos work fine even with the blob options set to video/mp4. The error is throwing me off.

Any guesses why it treats `getUseTransactionalMD5` as an undefined method in this case?

Here is the minimal code

```
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobRestProxy;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Exceptions\ServiceException;
$connString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=" . AZURE_ACCOUNTNAME . ";AccountKey=" . AZURE_KEY;
$blobRestProxy = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connString);
$content = fopen($file['tmp_name'], "r");
$contentType = "video/mp4";
$options = new CreateBlobOptions();
$options->setContentType($contenttype);
blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("mycontainer", "myblob", $content, $options);
```

Comment: How big are the other files which uploaded successfully? Also, which version of SDK you’re using?

Comment: It's not the size as it crashes even before it starts to upload.

We use the latest SDK via composer. Here is the composer.json

    `"require": {

  "php": ">=5.2.4",

                "microsoft/azure-storage-queue": "*",

                "microsoft/azure-storage-blob": "*"

 }`

There is actually a problem in this as traits were added to PHP with 5.4 but this will allow this code to run on PHP 5.2.4 which will break it anyways. Our server is set up on 5.6 so we are fine for now and soon we will be moving on to 5.7.

Comment: I stand corrected on my last comment. A 30 MB video works fine but a larger video fails so it may have something with size too.

Comment: Please try by changing this line of code `$options = new CreateBlobOptions();` to `$options = new CreateBlockBlobOptions();`

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you, Gaurav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, please change the following line of code:

```
$options = new CreateBlobOptions();
```

to

```
$options = new CreateBlockBlobOptions();
```

And that will fix the problem.

Essentially the reason you're getting this error is because of a breaking change in the SDK where they included the use of transaction MD5 in all upload/download methods. However, it was exposed in `CreateBlockBlobOptions` class through `getUseTransactionalMD5()` and not in `CreateBlobOptions` class. Because you're using latter instead of former, you're getting this error message.